# How to display data required using a database value

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new to crystal reports and I am trying to get round formulations.
I am trying to display certain data in a report by using a particular value from the database. All the data i need to display is within the value '1' of the database.
I have tried with an if statement, which seems to work but displays true and false instead of the actual data. Can anyone help me with this please?

```
if {database.column} = 1 then  
    true
else
    false
```

This is where I have got too, just need a little guidance please

Comment: In select expert {database.column} = 1

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do I put the under the suppression part?

Comment: In Report Menu there is select expert.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking in the 'format section' area

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code below:

```
if {database.column} = 1 then  
    database.column
else
    0
```